# Find complete word in text using Regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I am looking for a regex that would indicate if there is a certain complete word in a text, for example for the word `"cto"`:

- `"i am a cto"` - true
- `"i am a cto/developer"` - true
- `"cto"` - true
- `"i am a cto_developer"` - true
- `"ctools"` - false

I want the word to be case insensitive. Any thoughts?

Comment: And what is your language/script of using this regex?

Comment: i want to use it in a mysql query

Comment: What is your definition of a "word"? i.e. What are valid word characters? (The most common definition is: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`) The reason I ask is because the underscore is commonly considered to be a word character, so your: `"i am a cto_developer"` should be false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<=^|[^a-zA-Z0-9])<word>(?=$|[^a-zA-Z0-9])
```

Finds instances of `<word>` that are only preceded or succeeded by beginning or end of line/string or characters a-z or numbers 0-9. [Example](http://cl.ly/3a0z3o3t0l39270s3r2X) from [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/).

It would help if we knew what language this is in.

Comment: i want to use it in a mysql query

Answer (score 0):

You could either write an expression considering all the possibilities or use the \b anchor like `\bmyWord\b` and consider the _ a lost case because it's handled as part of the word so the "i am a cto_developer" will also return false.